# GameCenter real time Match will not start, stuck on connecting, in the app store not in sandbox

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator, game-center

I tested before submitting it of course, and it worked on simulators on iOS 6, but on 5.1 it wont work because the expectedPlayerCount always appears 1 not 0 !! just on 5.1!!
I searched about the problem and developers says that its network problem and sandbox problem so I submitted my app and it got approved !! and now I tried it and it always stuck on connecting!!!

- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController delegate:(id)theDelegate {

  if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

  matchStarted = NO;
  self.match = nil;
  self.presentingViewController = viewController;
  delegate = theDelegate;

  if (pendingInvite != nil) {

  ```
  [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  NSLog(@"findmatch");
  GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:pendingInvite] ;
  mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
  [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

  self.pendingInvite = nil;
  self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
  ```

  } else {

  ```
  [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  NSLog(@"findmatch2");
  GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] ;
  request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
  request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
  request.playersToInvite = pendingPlayersToInvite;

  GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
  mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

  [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

  self.pendingInvite = nil;
  self.pendingPlayersToInvite = nil;
  ```

  }

}

- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)theMatch {
  NSLog(@"%d",theMatch.expectedPlayerCount);
  [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  NSLog(@"didfind");
  self.match = theMatch;
  NSLog(@"%d",match.expectedPlayerCount);
  match.delegate = self;
  if (!matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
      NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
      [self lookupPlayers];
  }
  }

Please help I am getting so much Bad reviews !!

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to help you now, but did you make sure you had enabled Game Center in both places in iTunes Connect? This post: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/66773?tstart=0

tells you to enable in both the Manage Game Center section and the version you're going to upload (otherwise it might work in sandbox but not in the app store)

Hope it helps!